# Running Applescript: WorkFlowServiceRunner will not terminate

Tags: macos, applescript, keyboard-shortcuts, automator, workflowservice

I am trying to make a keyboard shortcut to launch terminal in OS X Mountain Lion.

After some research I found out that I can use **Automator** to achieve this:

http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tips-shortcuts/how-to-launch-any-app-with-a-keyboard-shortcut/

It works, but I noticed that whenever I launch a terminal using this method, a process called **WorkFlowServiceRunner** starts and *never terminates*. To make matters worse when I launch more terminals (or launch different applications using shortcuts, again, through Automator) *multiple* WorkFlowServiceRunner processes start and quickly eat up the memory.

I've also tried writing my own applescripts but the problem does not go away. This clearly looks like a memory leak. Is this a bug in OS X Automator? Is there a way to write an applescript so that the WorkFlowServiceRunner terminates after doing its job (e.g. launch a terminal)? Automator seems to be the most "native" way of getting this done and I do not want to use any 3rd party apps.

Comment: Hi, I lookked at the problem for awhile.  I was able to get at most two instances of WorkFlowServiceRunner running at the same time.  I looked at the running processes both with Activity Monitor.app and with the Unix command: "ps aux", and I couldn't replicate the issue.  I tried to fix it anyways by adding a "Run AppleScript" action to the end of the workflow that said: "tell current application to quit".  This didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I have made a slight update to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have noticed this from time to time.

One way around it would be to make your own service apps with a  Cocoa-AppleScript Applet.

It is not very hard to do. And I will try and guide you through it. It should only take you a couple of minutes.

**Step 1.**

Open your Application Applescript Editor. And go to the "File" Menu -> "New from Template" -> Cocoa-AppleScript Applet.app

[image]

**Step 2,**

Paste this code into the new documents.

```
property NSWorkspace : class "NSWorkspace"

tell current application's NSApp to setServicesProvider_(me)
NSUpdateDynamicServices()

my runAService()
    on runAService()

            NSWorkspace's sharedWorkspace()'s launchAppWithBundleIdentifier_options_additionalEventParamDescriptor_launchIdentifier_("com.apple.Terminal", current application's NSWorkspaceLaunchDefault, missing value, missing value)

        tell me to quit
    end runAService
```

**Step 3,**

**Compile**
(click this to compile)

[image]

and **Save** the app.

*Make sure the   ***show startup screen*** is unchecked in the Save dialogue.

Giving the app a name like *LaunchTerminal.app*

**Step 4**,

Click the "Bundle Contents"  button on the top right hand side of the document.

This will open the applications **contents** view.

[image]

Click the Action button and  then "Reveal in finder" sub menu.

[image]

**step** 5,

In the contents folder that opens in the finder you will see a file name "info.plist"

Open Terminal.app and type and run this code using the path to this file:

BUT make sure you do not include the ".plist" part of the name when entering it in Terminal.app

```
 /usr/bin/defaults write /Users/YourUserNameHere/myServiceApps/LaunchTerminal.app/Contents/Info  NSServices -array-add '{NSMenuItem={default="Launch Terminal";}; NSMessage="runAService"; NSSendTypes=();}'
```

( You can drag n drop the file into terminal to get the posix path string )
The path part looks like this: */Users/YourUserNameHere/myServiceApps/LaunchTerminal.app/Contents/Info*

This code should add an array to the plist file which is part of the apps way of broadcasting it has a service.

[image: The plist file Opened in a plist editor app]

**step** 6,

Compile and Save the App again.

Just to make sure it picks up the changes. ( I found I had to do this even though I should not have to)

**step** 7,

Double click the app to run it for the first time.

The App will quit straight away. But the first run should have broadcast that it has a service that should be registered with the system

**step** 8,

Open system Preferences and go to Services -> General (section)

And you will see the "Launch Terminal" service.

Set up your short cut as normal.

Hope this helps..

**UPDATE :**

I noticed that the tell application "Terminal" to activate.  Would not open my default Window groups if I had closed them all and quit Terminal before. The normal behaviour if I have done this is for my default window group to open. ( I have two Tabs open at startup each cd'd to a different path).

So I have change the open application to a cocoa way of doing it.

A do shell script with open the/application/path/.   will work also.

Comment: +1 for showing how to create a service this way (though there may be simpler solutions to the OP's problem).

Comment: Great post! Brilliant is probably a better description.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Butler](http://manytricks.com/butler/) or [QuicKeys](http://startly.com/products/quickeys/mac/4/). They both have endless "Trial periods."